# How to remove login popups when connected to a wifi network?

Tags: wi-fi, proxy

At my school there is a wifi network that blocks most websites. You don't need to log in, you simply connect and start browsing. But periodically a login page pops up. The problem is, this login page is also blocked by the network. So, all I can do is go back out of that page, and it will reappear every now and then.

Is there any way to disable the login page?

Answer (score -1):

I don't think there is a method for doing this (though I stand to be corrected). I believe that Android only shows this page when it detects a login request from the network. Maybe your school network frequently refreshes its login keys whether it requires a login or not which causes Android to react by bringing up the page?

Comment: Please use comments to write opinions or altogether do not post them unless you can back them with independently verifiable facts and credible technical sources.